# creating a VIF or a Chunking beetwen eth0 and eth1 in order to have only a network interface made by the bridging of them

Tags: linux-networking

i have a linux server (RHEL5) inside an HP Enclosure system, i would to create a bridge or a VIF or a chunking (sorry because i am a newbie in this operation) able to hide eth0 and eth1 as two different devices and to show them me as a single device instead.

If anyone can give me some information about this operation, it will be very useful.

thank you 
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Red Hat Enterprise Linux allows administrators to bind multiple network interfaces together into a single channel using the bonding kernel module and a special network interface called a channel bonding interface. Channel bonding enables two or more network interfaces to act as one, simultaneously increasing the bandwidth and providing redundancy.](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces-chan.html)

Comment: Yes sciurus i have solved exactly following instruction about bonding in RedHat site.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a bridge in the strict networking sense (simply put, a layer 2 device which passes packets from one interface out of the other), then you should be able to do this like so:

1) Edit both /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 to remove any IP address/netmask/gateway configuration and add a specified bridge. It should look something like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0 (or eth1)
HWADDR=00:11:22:33:44:55
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
```

2) Edit a new file, /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0 which contains your IP address information. This should look something like this:

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=yes
DELAY=0
BOOTPROTO=static
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
IPADDR=192.168.1.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

Your IP address is then assigned on the bridge, so should be accessible from either interface. Also packets should be forwarded between the interfaces. If this wasn't what you meant by the question then my apologies, this is how to set up a bridge but it may be that a bridge isn't what you need, the question wasn't 100% clear...